# Prevent double kfree in kernel code?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working on some system calls in the linux kernel. Since double `kfree()` raises an error, what could be a good safeguard against that ?

One obvious idea I had in mind was to set the pointer to `NULL` after `kfree()` and check if it's `NULL` before next possible `kfree()`. I am not sure if this is the right way to do so. Please guide me.

Comment: Same as non kernel code: know who owns the pointer.

Comment: @MooingDuck sorry I didn't get you. I'm referring to a global pointer within the code, if that is what you meant ?

Comment: `Since double kfree() raises an error, what could be a good safeguard against that?` - The best safeguard is to eliminate all double `kfree`, as it is errorneous usage of kernel API. If you want to **debug concrete problem**, use any method which helps you in this concrete case. If you want to **allow** double `kfree` usage, then you need to mark pointer as already freed, the simplest way is to set some flag in the freed memory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so my suggested strategy using NULL seems ok  ?

Comment: @bawejakunal How do you prevent double free in normal code?

Comment: @bawejakunal: It is always correct to call `kfree()` with NULL pointer. Such call does nothing. Is this an actual intention of your question?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you want to avoid that situation by *design*. Few examples:

- `kmalloc()` on your driver's `.probe`, and you `kfree()` on your driver's `.remove`. Then you are good, the `probe/remove`  calls are balanced by the kernel.
- `kmalloc()` on your char driver's `.open`, and you `kfree()` on your driver's `.release`. Also good, the `open/release` calls are balanced by the kernel.

However, in certain cases, where for some reason you just want to deallocate the object **if** it was allocated, then your approach of NULLifying the pointer and check before `kfree()` is perfectly fine. (I would say it's a trace of something poorly designed... but I've been there and done it ;)

In the future, when you have a question like this, where you want to see if an approach is popular enough, you can browse the kernel sources. Look for similar drivers and see what patterns are used. It will give you great insight!